# how to change textsize in textView by clicking on button

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm not good at programming and especially at android, I've made 2 buttons one for making text size big, one for making text size small, and also i made condition that when text size is reached to limit size the button will stop increasing or decreasing text size. it didn't work, when i press btnSmall or btnBig nothing happen, I don't know what is missing here, please i need help... here's what I've done

Java file:

```
private Button btnSmallTxt, btnBigTxt;
private tvAdminPosts;
int txtSize = 14;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.client);
    btnSmallTxt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSmall);
    btnBigTxt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBig);

   btnSmallTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (tvAdminPosts.getTextSize() == 15||tvAdminPosts.getTextSize() ==16||tvAdminPosts.getTextSize() ==17|tvAdminPosts.getTextSize() ==18){
                txtSize--;
                tvAdminPosts.setTextSize(txtSize);
            } else {
                txtSize += 0;
                tvAdminPosts.setTextSize(txtSize);
            }
        }
    });

    btnBigTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (tvAdminPosts.getTextSize() == 14 ||tvAdminPosts.getTextSize() == 15 || tvAdminPosts.getTextSize() == 16 || tvAdminPosts.getTextSize() == 17){
                txtSize++;
                tvAdminPosts.setTextSize(txtSize);
            } else if (tvAdminPosts.getTextSize() == 18) {
                txtSize+= 0;
                tvAdminPosts.setTextSize(txtSize);
            } else{
                txtSize+= 0;
                tvAdminPosts.setTextSize(txtSize);
            }
        }
    });
```

XML file: 
in the xml i made the textView textsize 14 sp
to start with 14 as i write in java but i don't
know if i'm in the right way or what ??

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAdminPosts"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.06"
    android:textColor="#fff600"
    android:maxLines="100"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:maxLength="1000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
   android:id="@+id/btnBig"
   android:layout_width="150dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:text="@string/large_txt"
   android:textColor="#ffffff"
   android:textSize="7pt"
   android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
   android:id="@+id/btnSmall"
   android:layout_width="150dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:text="@string/small_txt"
   android:textColor="#ffffff"
   android:textSize="5pt"
   android:textStyle="bold" />
```

I searched a lot in this but i didn't find anything simple like what I've trying to do
I would be grateful if someone just helped me. Sorry for my bad English

Comment: You are comparing your text size in pixels, when what you want is dp. See the documentation of getTextSize() in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getTextSize%28%29

Comment: thanks man it worked.. but it stopped after one click then the 2 buttons don't do anything, could you tell me what is wrong with the condition.

Comment: It makes sense, if you pressed the btnSmallText Button first, because after that, neither of your click entering conditions are valid.

Comment: @issathink there is no error showing to me, but the problem is when i click on btnSmall or btnBig it makes the textSize increase by one and then stop i don't know what is the problem here ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getTextSize%28%29), `getTextSize()` returns the text size in `pixels`, not `sp` as you are defining it.

```
android:textSize="14sp"
```

Either change your XML attribute to

```
android:textSize="14px"
```

so all your code logic works.

Or find a way to translate `px` value to `sp`.

**Edit:** About your second question, when you use `setTextSize()` with your increased value, it will set the text size in `sp`. Again, according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize%28float%29), the unit type of this method, by default, is "sp" or "scaled pixels".

As you are always checking the text size in `px`, your condition is invalid and, thus, nothing happens.

The solution is specifying the unit type that you want, being pixels, in your case. 
So you have to use:

```
tvAdminPosts.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, yourSizeValue);
```

Comment: Awesome Man Its Worked